# React Final Form: is it possible to submit in edit form even no changes made in fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

in React Final Form is `pristine` props can be make it always false? or in the other words is it possible to submit in edit form even no changes made in fields?

I already checking the documentation but unfortunately still no solution of this.

```
<Form
                initialVal={form.current}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```